# What is the meaning of views displays?

Tags: views

I know how to create a view as a page or block and etc.

But The **Displays** seems meaning I can create lots of views?

This following is my guess:

- Is it will group all kind of views to a single page?
- Does **Displays** just easily use the previous view configuration and
  just Put similar view together to manager easily?

[image]

Comment: When adding a new display, the Master display settings will be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views displays helps you manage your views that are similarly the same.

Basic example is articles:

On your home page, you want a simple block that shows 5 articles, no pager.
At the bottom of this block, you want a link "read all articles".
It redirects you to a page with all the articles, 10 per page, with a pager at the end.

Instead of creating 2 views, which is a waste of time, you'll create one view with 2 displays.

For this example, you will create two views displays, one "Block" and one "Page".
First you create your "Page" display (or "Block", as you want), set it to filter only articles content type, show the title and the date of publication.
Then you can create the other view display, and you only need to override the "Pager" settings.

Tomorrow, if you add an image to your articles, and you want them to appears on both the block and the page, you just need to add the image in the fields, and it will appear on both views display.

Beware that each views display has its own purpose, for example "Feed" will all you to create Rss display, "Page" needs it's own URI, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should create:

- **New view** when you need a **new set of data** selected.
- **New display** in existing view when you need different page or block for **already existing data set**.

Of course border between the two is fluid. Use your experience and intuition to decide, with above as strong, but only guideline.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Does **New display** just easily use of the **previous view** configuration? Or Put similar view together to manager easily?

Comment: And what's meaning of Attachment?

Comment: @Wooden If what you really wanted to know is what's the meaning of the attachment, see the question I pointed in "possible duplicate". If you want discussion about views - sorry, I'm here to answer questions without discussion.